# Git checkout into a work directory with symbolic links

Tags: git, git-diff, git-checkout, git-archive

In this case the repository does not have symbolic links, but the working directory I am checking out into does.  Why?  I have an existing repository for a website.  To simplify matters, let's say the directory structure for this is:

```
bin
www
```

But now to save some money I have parked this website under an existing ISP account so that the *www* directory is now a sub-directory of *www* named *parked-domain*.  So the actual directory structure is now:

```
bin
www
   parked-domain
```

My solution I thought was to create a directory named *workdir* with two symbolic links named *bin* and *www* that referred to the *bin* and *parked-domain* directories in the prior directory structure.  Then I would do a checkout command with the **--work-tree** parameter specifying this *workdir* directory and hope that because the *bin* and *www* directories within *workdir* already exist, the checkout command would not recreate them.  But alas, the symbolic links are deleted and regular directories are created.  Is there a solution to this problem other than copying entire directory structures?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that this is doable.  What one would like is (1) The ability to checkout just a single sub-directory and (2) Be able to override the directory name to use in the working directory when checking out this sub-directory.  Something like the following:

```
git --work-tree=$HOME/www checkout-tree master www parked-domain
```

By the way, CVS, which everyone loves to knock these days, can do this.